# What is the use case for doOnSuccess vs onSuccess in rxJava

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-kotlin

I'm confusing about use case for doOnSuccess in rxJava.
Let's see the code:

Case 1:

```
networkApi.callSomething()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())               
    .doOnSuccess(__ -> showLog(SUCCESS))
    .doOnError(__ -> showLog(ERROR))
    .subscribeBy(
             onSuccess = {//Do something}, 
             onError = {//Show log here}
          )
```

Case 2:

```
networkApi.callSomething()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())               
    .subscribeBy(
             onSuccess = {
               //Do something
               showLog(SUCCESS)
             }, 
             onError = {showLog(ERROR)}
          )
```

As normal, I think case 2 is fine.
I also have referred some source code in github and I saw some people do like case 1.
I try to ask myself what is the use case for `doOnSuccess` here ?

Is there any use case that we need apply **`doOnSuccess()`** operator ?

Comment: doOnSuccess is a Disposable CallBack Method on the other hand onSuccess is Lamda Expression of doOnSuccess  from subscribeBy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Singles and Maybes have a success signal and the handler has the `onSuccess` method called. Often though, you'd want to side-effect the success signal at various points in the flow so there is the `doOnSuccess` operator.

```java
getUserAsSingle()
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.doOnSuccess(user -> ui.showUser(user))
.flatMap(user -> 
     getUserFavoritesAsSingle(user)
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
)
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.doOnSuccess(userFavs -> ui.showUserFavorites(userFavs))
.flatMap(userFavs -> 
     updateLoginCounter(userFavs.userId)
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
)
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
subscribe(newCounter -> ui.showLoginCount(newCounter),
    error -> ui.showError(error));
```

Answer (score 1):

One use case I normally apply for `doOnSuccess()` is to enforce some triggers when the call is successful. For example, I have a function to fetch user data in a common class

```
fun getUserData(userId: Int) {
    userDataApi(userId)              
        .doOnSuccess { fetchAllImages() }
        .doOnError { Log.e(it) }
}
```

As you can see, there is no subscription yet. And the one who wants to use the above function can call it later on.

```
getUserData
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe()
```

And if `getUserData` succeeds, it will always call `fetchAllImages()`.

Comment: Is there any case to use those method together ? And which one will be called first ?

Comment: I have not yet found any difference between 2 of them, it is kind of based on your preference when you use them together